# Why Vue.js template can't interact it's script?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using vue.js with axios and I'm trying to make an ajax call when I click a certain button. My problem is that my button's onclick event can't find it's function. Can someone explain to me **Why can't my template interact with my script in my view?**

Here's a short example of what I'm trying to achieve.

Example.vue

```
<template>
    <button onclick="someClickFunction();"></button>
</template>

<script>
    function someClickFunction(){
        console.log("You've pressed the button");
    }

    export default {
        name: "button-view",
    }
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in vue you must write functions in the methods object and onclick == @click

```
<template>
        <button @click="someClickFunction();"></button>
    </template>

    <script>
        export default {
            name: "button-view",
            methods: {
              someClickFunction(){
                console.log("You've pressed the button");
              }
            }
        }
    </script>

    <style scoped>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because in vue, you don't use the native onclick event.

Instead you use the

```
v-on:click
```

or the

```
@click
```

Better check the documentation. It is written very thoroughly
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html

EDIT:
You also have error on your script. All functions must be declared inside the methods of the vue instance